Lua attempt to index a nil value vs code
I am trying to run this code but lua keeps giving me errors. The package exists at the specified location. Here is the code - thanks!:
package.path = package.path .. ';C:/Users/xyz/AppData/Roaming/luarocks/share/lua/5.4/?.lua;C:/Users/xyz/AppData/Roaming/luarocks/share/lua/5.4/?/init.lua'
package.cpath = package.cpath .. ';C:/Users/xyz/AppData/Roaming/luarocks/lib/lua/5.4/?.so'

-- Require the modules using their module names
local npairs = require('nvim-autopairs')
local Rule = require('nvim-autopairs.rule')
local cond = require('nvim-autopairs.conds')

-- Setup nvim-autopairs
npairs.setup({})

-- Add custom rules
npairs.add_rules({
  Rule("$", "$", "tex")
    :with_move(cond.after_text("$"))
    :with_move(cond.before_text("$")),
  Rule("$$", "$$", "tex")
    :with_move(cond.after_text("$$"))
    :with_move(cond.before_text("$$"))
})


Why do you add .so (Linux) file type extension to package.cpath on Windows?

When it says "index a nil value", what it means is that you are trying to get something (an index) from nothing (nil). Lua has two main means of indexing a thing, thing["index"] and thing.index.
I highly suspect that you are running into an unused global variable somewhere, which default to nil. It might not be in the code you posted, I can't find any issue with globals directly.
The only globals you use here are package and require. Maybe your Lua runtime is missing one of those. Try to print(package, require) and see if you see the word nil printed anywhere then you are missing one of those.
The other option is that npairs or cond is nil. This would be a problem with the nvim-autopairs library.
Either way you should check for things being nil whenever you get this error.

you're not "trying to get something (an index)", it is not the index you want to get, you're using the index to get a value. if require were nil you'd get an error for attempting to call a nil value, not for indexing one. : is an indexing operation too btw.

You can see it as either. You can get the index resulting in the value, or you can get the value by the index. I'm unsure what the point of your comment was.

the point of my comment was to point out false claims in your answer so you can correct/improve it. an indexing operation does not "try to get ... an index" as you claim. it gets a value at the given index. you cannnot "see it as either". you cannot index something without an index so you need an index in the first place.

I can and do see people think of it as both.

That doesn't make it a correct statement  ;-) You cannot index without an index, end of discussion.
